# Problem with IE in grab/drag scenario

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, browser, cross-browser

I have a project where users can interact with a carousel like slide show, and drag between slides instead of using an arrow/number navigation. JS is based on the following plug in:

http://nooshu.com/explore/jquery-iphone-animation/

The issue is, in IE, if a user grabs inside the carousel and the mouse leaves the container element, the UI freaks out. If you play around with it, you'll see what I mean.

Is there a way to tell IE to handle the drag/click event to mimic firefox and chrome? I'm sure this is a common problem with IE and UI design.

Help!

EDIT: This also happens in Chrome. Firefox is the only browser that handles this in an intuitive way.

Comment: I get the same issue in Chrome

Comment: I was told this was an IE bug, but I only tried it in Firefox. I get it in Chrome as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When, in IE, the mouse leaves the square, it's not releasing the mousedown event.  So even when you let the button go, the plugin still thinks that the mouse is down.

Is it possible then that you wrap the plugin in say a div and on the div have a mouseleave event and force the plugin to execute mouseup?

I think you should be able to use the jQuery keyword "trigger" to do it.

Comment: Could be. Upvoted for a good suggestion of what the answer could be, but not technically an answer. If no one else chimes in I'll karma you up :)

Comment: I would also mention it's not just the click release. When the mouse leaves the window, the content stops scrolling.

Comment: It does but what i saw was when my mouse re-entered the square the content would scroll as i moved the mouse.  if i clicked in the box it would return to normal operation indicating that the mouseup event had fired and released the handle

Comment: Yeah, I'd just like to know if there is a way to tell IE and Chrome to pretend that they're firefox in the manner they handle mouse click events in this manner.

Comment: oh, no i'm pretty sure you're outta luck there.  IE does things its own way and don't ever try to get around it! :)